# Vim formatter (=) double-indents on multi-line segments?

Tags: vim, vi

I have some code:

```
    Vector3 targetCoords = this.GetFiringSolution(
        targetObject,
        targetObject.root.rigidbody.velocity,
        muzzle,
        verticalRotator.root.rigidbody.velocity,
        projectileForce 
    )
```

but when I use (gg+G) in vim it turns this into

```
    Vector3 targetCoords = this.GetFiringSolution(
            targetObject,
            targetObject.root.rigidbody.velocity,
            muzzle,
            verticalRotator.root.rigidbody.velocity,
            projectileForce 
    )
```

Here is my :set output:

```
--- Options ---
  autoindent          cindent             fileformat=unix     history=50          modified            scroll=28           smartindent       notextmode
  background=dark     diffexpr=MyDiff()   filetype=cs         hlsearch            number              shiftwidth=4        syntax=cs           visualbell
  backup              expandtab           helplang=en         incsearch           ruler               showmatch           tabstop=4           window=57
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  comments=sO:* -,mO:*  ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,:///,://
  formatoptions=croql
  keymodel=startsel,stopsel
  selection=exclusive
  selectmode=mouse,key
  viminfo=%,'100,<50,s10,h,rA:,rB:
  whichwrap=b,s,<,>,[,]
  wildignore=*.meta,*.swp
```

Is there anyway to stop this behaviour? I tried looking into cimoptions but didn't fully understand. This happens for multi-line function calls (and similar things) in both C# and PHP - probably others.

I also tried turning on si/ai and both, but didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the vim help for `cinoptions-values`:

```
    +N    Indent a continuation line (a line that spills onto the next)
          inside a function N additional characters.  (default
          'shiftwidth').
          Outside of a function, when the previous line ended in a
          backslash, the 2 * N is used.
```

So it seems like you can either disable `cindent` altogether or you will have to live with double indentation outside of a function.